# how to implement token base form submission in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have been trying to create my own OOPs style register login system in php, i have implemented some security features like xss protection using htmlentites(), prepare method for SQLinjection protection and token based form submission for csrf protection(currently i am stuck implementing this functions in my code, getting "Invalid token" while submitting form data).
But I am not very sure it is good enough for secure site to produce for real live project or not. And i would like you to review my codes, Please help me to solve implementing token base form submission in my code and suggest me the way to improve my coding style in my current code.

This is my register.php page

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
session_start();


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    include "Db_handlers.php";
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $res = $db->createUser($_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"], $_POST["re-password"], $_POST['token']);
    print_r($res);
    /*if($res){
        echo "test";
    }
    else {
        echo $res;
    }*/
}
$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));

?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" />      
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" />     
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" />      
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="repassword">Re-Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="re-password" value="" />       
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my DB handler class

```
 <?php 
    require 'functions.php';

    class DbHandler {

    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {

    try{

    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=task_manager", "root" , "");

    // echo "Connected";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        //die($e->getMessage());
        echo "Connection Failed: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    }

    public function createUser($name, $email, $password, $repassword, $utoken) {
    // $error = array();
    $error = '';
    $required_fields = array($name, $email, $password, $repassword);
    $fields = array_map('trim', $required_fields);
    if (in_array(null, $fields)) {
        $error = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
    }

    else if($this->valid_token($utoken) == false){
       $error = "Invalid Token...!!!";
    }

    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $error = 'Please enter a valid email address !';
    }

    else if(strlen($password) < 6){
        $error = "Password must be atleast 6 characters"; 
    }

    else if($password !== $repassword){
        $error = "Password do n\' t match!!";
    }
    else{
       $name = escape($name);
       $email = escape($email);
       $password_hash = escape($password);
       // First check if user already existed in db
       if (!$this->isUserExists($email)) {
       // Generating password hash
       $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost'=>12]);
      // insert query
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, password_hash, status) values(:name, :email, :password_hash, 1)");
      //$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $password_hash);
      $result = $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name,':email' => $email,':password_hash' => $password_hash));;
     //$stmt->close();
     // Check for successful insertion
     if ($result) {
     // User successfully inserted
         return $result;
      } else {
      // Failed to create user
        $error = "Failed to create user";
      }
      } else {
         // User with same email already existed in the db
         $error = "User already exists";
      }
      }
        return $error;
    }




    private function isUserExists($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from users WHERE email = :email");
        //$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
        //$stmt->bind_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
        //$stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
    }


    public function valid_token($token){
       if(!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $token != $_SESSION['token'])
       return false; 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Ever heard of code indentation? This is horrible to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really hard to read... You should indent it properly.

Back to your question. It seems, you just return `false`, if your token is incorrect, but your forget to return `true`, if it is correct. If your return nothing, you implicitly return `null`, which evaluates to `false`. I guess, your code works, if your change `valid_token` like this:

```
public function valid_token($token){
    return isset($_SESSION['token']) && $token == $_SESSION['token'];
}
```

Comment: now it works! able to submit the form when i change this in validation part else if(!$this->valid_token($utoken)){
   $error = "Invalid Token...!!!";
  } thank you. @Philipp is it ok to write code like this for token base form submission?? is my code ok for such security feature? Thank you